# R fails to load any packages

Tags: r, package

Using 32 bit R on a Windows 7 64 bit machine, I currently cannot load any packages at all. All packages install fine, but throw an error when I try to load, e.g.

```
> library(quadprog)

Loading required package: quadprog
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
  unable to load shared object ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.1/library/quadprog/libs/i386/quadprog.dll’:
LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: package ‘quadprog’ could not be loaded
```

(This example shows quadprog, but any other package throws the same error.)

I've installed exactly this set of packages on to 100 or so different PCs across different companies, and never had any issues, so it must be something pretty specific to the setup in this company.

This error occurs using both R2.14.1, and R3.1.0, and is not affected by the 64 bit version being present or not.

The core libraries seem to load fine (e.g. stats, methods, base etc), however trying to load any additional packages early by e.g. including a library(quadprog) in .Rprofile.site throws the same error.

The libraries themselves seem fine, and are exactly as I have them on another machine that works fine. They are 32 bit, which confuses me slightly given the error message...

Installing the libraries to a different location seems to make no difference.

Some main path variables are:

```
HOME:        \\\\Globalinfra.net\\users\\P-#\\Userdata\\aUser\\My Documents

R_HOME:      C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0

R_LIBS_USER: \\\\Globalinfra.net\\users\\P-#\\Userdata\\aUser\\My Documents/R/win-library/3.1

TEMP:        C:\\Users\\aUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp

TMP:         C:\\Users\\aUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
```

The user has write access to all of these folders. The error still occurs even when logged in as admin.

(Incidentally, packages load fine in the 64 bit version of R, but I cannot use that due to a known issue with Rcpp.)

Comment: How did you install the libraries? The error occurs when it tries to load a dll. Have you tried installing the packages from source (you'd need to install Rtools first)? If you try this, you might need to use an older Rtools version because "some of the tools for 32 bit compiles became incompatible with obsolete versions of R".

Comment: Does the DLL exist at the indicated location?